# Check value within range or not php

Tags: php, arrays, function, output

I want to check value with in range or not suppose if I have range `D1 to D40` and if I enter `D20` then it returns value with in range.

I check several solution but this are for only integer not for both string and integer.

**EDIT**

Range will be dynamic like `AA20 to AA30 or like AC10D to AC30D`

Comment: how about removing the string and only use integer to check if it is in range, and then putting the string back with integer once done

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific as to what format your values are, and what you consider 'in range'? How are you interpreting the string values? Is B5 in the range A0 to C9? Are there even values with a different character?

Comment: Replace D with any number. Please add some of the solutions you tried. This should, out of the box, be very easy.

Comment: @Joost yes suppose if i have range A1 to A30 and if i enter B20 then it returns not in range it returns only if its within A1 to A30

Comment: But will you ever do tests where the characters are unequal? I.e. test if B5 is in A1 to C7? Or A1 to C4?

Comment: @Baig ya its easy if i remove string but i simplay giving example for range. Range will be dynamic like AA20 to AA25 or like EC10A to EC30A.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write something simpler like this...

```
$arr = range(1,40); //<--- Creating a range of 1 to 40 elements..
array_walk($arr,function (&$v){ $v = 'D'.$v;}); //<--- Concatenating D to all the elements..
echo in_array('D20',$arr) ? 'Found' : 'Not Found'; //<-- The search part.
```

<kbd>[Demonstration](https://eval.in/146177)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

First, you should remove the letter `D` from your string variable, like this:

```
// This is your first variable:
$rang1="D5";

// This is your second rang variable:
$rang2="D20";

$rang1=str_replace("D","",$rang1);
$rang2=str_replace("D","",$rang2);
$rang=$rang2-$rang1;
echo $rang;
```

---

**Or if your variable looks like this:**

```
$rang="D5 TO D20";
```

**you can use the following:**

```
$rang="D5 TO D20";
$rang=explode(" TO ",$rang);
$rang1=rang[0];
$rang2=rang[1];

$rang1=str_replace("D","",$rang1);
$rang2=str_replace("D","",$rang2);
$rang=$rang2-$rang1;
echo $rang;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// 1. build up array of valid entries
$prefix = "D";
$rangeArray = array();
for($i = 1; $i <= 40; $i++) {
    $rangeArray[] = $prefix . $i;
}

...

// 2. check against that array:
$inRange = in_array($needle, $rangeArray); // boolean
```

To get the position in the range:

```
$pos = array_search($needle, $rangeArray); // integer or false if not found
```

Where $needle would be your input value.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will work with ranges with different letter in the beginning like `A10` to `B30` *(assuming `A20` is in that range, but `A40` is not)*:

```
$min = "A10";
$max = "B30";
$test = "A20";

$min_ascii = chr($min[0]);
$max_ascii = chr($max[0]);
$test_ascii = chr($max[0]);

$min_number = substr($min, 1);
$max_number = substr($max, 1);
$test_number = substr($test, 1);

if ($min_ascii <= $test_ascii and $test_ascii <= $max_ascii
    and $min_number <= $test_number and $test_number <= $max_number)
{
    echo "$test is in the range from $min to $max";
}
```